# Uncaught exception from the OnConnectionAsync method of an IConnectionAdapter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ssl, kestrel

I work with **asp.net core 2.2** and start the app **as console application (kestrel)** on our internet server.
A **valid public cert** is attached (.pfx, see configuration in appsettings.json below).
**Problem:**

- If I test the app internally and externally over the internet, **I cannot comprehend any problem (anything works as expected).**
- I have no problems to start the app.
- But sporadically (not to comprehend, not to provocate), I have error messages (exceptions to crashes) in the console (see below).
- when the crashes occur, they usually occur multiple times (mostly > 10 times) - unfortunately, I cannot say in what time frame (as no timestamp’s are wrote to the console).
- Further, I often (strangeways) have a lot of empty lines on the console after the error messages).

**Appsettings.json:**

```
   {
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
,
    "Kestrel": {
        "EndPoints": {
            "Http": {
                "Url": "http://localhost:5001"
            },
            "HttpsInlineCertFile": {
                "Url": "https://192.168.3.3",
                "Protocols": "Http1AndHttp2",  
                "Certificate": {
                    "Path": "./certificate_2021.pfx",
                    "Password": "Passwort",
                    "AllowInvalid": "true"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: The cert is **not** imported in the cert-store of the server (as I think, this is not needed).
I have searched the internet for days now and have not found any hint, that drives me in the right direction.
**Thanks for any help.**
**Exception:**

```
    fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
      Uncaught exception from the OnConnectionAsync method of an IConnectionAdapter.
System.Net.InternalException: Exception of type 'System.Net.InternalException' was thrown.
   at System.Net.SecurityStatusAdapterPal.GetSecurityStatusPalFromInterop(SECURITY_STATUS win32SecurityStatus, Boolean attachException)
   at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.GenerateToken(Byte[] input, Int32 offset, Int32 count, Byte[]& output)
   at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.NextMessage(Byte[] incoming, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.PartialFrameCallback(AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ThrowIfExceptional()
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndAuthenticateAsServer(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<>c.<AuthenticateAsServerAsync>b__51_1(IAsyncResult iar)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https.Internal.HttpsConnectionAdapter.InnerOnConnectionAsync(ConnectionAdapterContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.HttpConnection.ApplyConnectionAdaptersAsync()
```

Comment: .NET Core 2.2 is EOL, try to use 2.1 or switch to 3.1. They are LTS releases are receive a different fixes periodically

Comment: YOu probably have a TLS issue.  Microsoft disabled TLS 1.0/1.1 in June on servers.  So clients now have to specify the TLS version either 1.2/1.3.  I do not think 1.3 will work with Core  2.2 but 1.2 will and it is working in console.  So you need to add to your c# the following : ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

Comment: @jdweng: Thanks - this (TLS 1.1) could be a logical reason for the behavior - crash as soon as a client load the app with 1.1 - not able to comprehend as I test with 1.2... I will investigate this more in detail now...

Comment: The certificate has to be compatible with TLS 1.2 (See wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) and the operating system has to support TLS 1.2.  Core runs on a machine the the operating system sits under Core.  Core is like Net which runs under Windows (and other operating systems).  So you can run TLS 1.2 with Core 2.2 but the operating system has to support TLS 1.2

Comment: TLS 1.2 works without problems end-to-end - that's NOT the problem. I was able to configure IE11 (only browser I found) ONLY for TLS 1.1 (in the hope to be able to provocate the crashes). "Unfortunately", I was not able to provocate crashes with only TLS 1.1. I investigate further....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think (hope so), I have solved the problem "implicitly" (to early to be sure finally):

- For other reasons, I have added a **redirect from http to https** a few days ago in startup.cs
- Since then, it seems, I had no more crashes in the console

I cannot control, what kind of users/tools access the app over the internet.
So... from my point of view (not to comprehend / provoke by use the "legal" app over standard browser over https) this may be a plausible reason.

Added code in startup.cs

```
 if (env.IsDevelopment())
   {
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
   }
    else
    {
      app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
      app.UseHsts();
      app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions().AddRedirectToHttps(StatusCodes.Status301MovedPermanently, 443));
  }
```